# How to find the sum of many raster files in arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster-calculator

I have a list of 576 raster files for which I need to find the SUM. Obviously using raster calculator one by one would be tedious. Any easy script in Arcpy to do this?

Comment: Why is your first keyword "qgis" when you are asking about ArcPy?

Comment: For an individual raster, you can use [`arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(in_raster, nodata_to_value=0).sum()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) to get the sum of all values. Just iterate over all of your rasters and accumulate these individual sums into a grand total.

Answer (score 2):

rdebruyn-esristaff has made a python script available for download that does this called sumrasters.py.zip.

It is available at this thread:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/25945

or direct download:

https://geonet.esri.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/187485-27013/sumrasters.py.zip